# Unable to install Juniper.junos role Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am trying to install `Juniper.junos` role using Ansible, but I am getting an error.

Below is what I am trying and the error message.

```
root@ubuntu:~# ansible-galaxy install Juniper.junos
- downloading role 'junos', owned by Juniper
 [WARNING]: - Juniper.junos was NOT installed successfully: ERROR! - sorry, Juniper.junos was not found on https://galaxy.ansible.com.

ERROR! - you can use --ignore-errors to skip failed roles and finish processing the list.
```

Comment: It is working now. I just tried $sudo ansible-galaxy install  Juniper.junos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working with sudo:  **sudo ansible-galaxy install Juniper.junos**

Answer (score 1):

Kindly use below command for installation, it will work good.

sudo ansible-galaxy install git+https://github.com/Juniper/ansible-junos-stdlib.git,,Juniper.junos

```
[root@host /Users/root] sudo ansible-galaxy install git+https://github.com/Juniper/ansible-junos-stdlib.git,,Juniper.junos
- extracting Juniper.junos to /homes/babud/.ansible/roles/Juniper.junos 
- Juniper.junos was installed successfully
```

---